# socket.io does'nt work on chrome mobile, but it does in incognito mode

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, sockets, google-chrome

I'm working with nodeJs and socket.io under AngularJS.

The sockets work really well on desktop (all browsers). But not on mobile.

Well...
Socket d'ont work on chrome mobile, expect in incognito mode. 
Here is a bit of code:

SERVER SIDE:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    user = {
        id: socket.id,
        socket: socket
    };
    console.log('connection received');
    console.log(user.id);
    socket.emit('files', lib.all());
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
socket.on('files', function(data){
    var streams = data;
    if(streams){
        $scope.streams = streams;  
    } 
});
```

the lib.all() function work fine. 
And I've got a angular Factory to handle socket.io (which also work fine).

In chrome mobile socket does not received or emit anything. But they work as expected in incognito mode. 
As well they work in firefox for android.

I'm not an expert in Android neither in chrome. But I suspect there is something special/strange happening. A Firewall? A proxy?

Does someone know a workaround for this?

Thanks, and have a good day!

P.S : on chrome Desktop with emulation enabled it's working fine.

EDIT: 
I founded what's the heck:

Chrome mobile 'data saver' option. Ths one who reduce the data using google servers.

Sockets are probably in trouble passing by Google servers.. still a workaround could be great.

Comment: I've got this as well except that it doesn't load at all even in incognito. :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an integrity attribute with any javascript?

I had a problem with a CDN for bootstrap.js having a SHA-256 mismatch, which resulted in the content being blocked by Chrome Data Saver.

I fixed this by changing `src="//my.cdn.js` to `src="https://my.cdn.js`

Comment: The above code changed completely in my project,
I switched front-end framework and the whole code had been re-done from scratch... 
So I cannot answer you.
But it's possible yes, the problem was indeed because of a mix of sources, and a bad socket.io host definition. 

Hope it helps anyhow :)